# Error for React Native and unsure what is it about

Tags: javascript, react-native

Recently i tried to build own mobile apps by using React Native but during my course of learning, i am hitting this error which i am not sure why is it

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in C:\Users\john\Desktop\test\test.js: C:/Users/john/Desktop/test/test.js: Unexpected token (9:9)
7 |     let testData = this.props.data.map(function(cardData, i){
8 |       return {
>  9 |          <ListItem>
     |          ^
  10 |               <Left>
```

the arrow of error message is highlighted on  tag where i am using native-base
  11 |                 {cardData.name}
  12 |

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap your components in () not {}.

```
return (
    <ListItem>
        etc...
    </ListItem>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

On line 8, you have

```
   return {
```

However, you need to return your JSX enclosed in `()`, not `{}`. Wrap your `<ListItem>` this way and the error will go away.